# Handle element resize in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with two divs:

```
<div id="childContainer">
  <div id="child">
    <a class="btn btn-primary testBtn1" ng-show="!vm.hideButton">Test Button 1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-secondary testBtn2">Test Button 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to keep the `childContainer` div the same height as the `child` div, specifically when I hide `testBtn1`. Here's the watch function inside my directive's controller which should do that:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return vm.child.height(); //vm.child is a jQuery object
}, function(){
  vm.childContainer.height(vm.child.height()); //vm.childContainer is a jQuery object
});
```

However, this isn't working as expected. It's as if the watch function triggers too late. You can view the issue [here on my plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/28ylh0?p=preview).

Comment: Change your watch to the following: `$scope.$watch('vm.child.height', function(){ vm.childContainer.height(vm.child.height()); })`.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that, but then the watch event didn't trigger. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using controllerAs?

Comment: Yeah gimme a sec. I just realized you're putting a watch on the return value of a function--`$watch` doesn't work that way. You put a watch on a variable, not a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$watch` is supposed to take in the variable you want to monitor, *not* the value.

```
return vm.child.height(); //vm.child is a jQuery object
```

Here, you are returning the *value* of `vm.child.height();`. Change that to:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.child.height()', function(){
  vm.childContainer.height(vm.child.height()); //vm.childContainer is a jQuery object
});
```

Comment: I'll repost my comment on the answer.. I tried that, but then the event didn't trigger. I also tried watching vm.child.offsetHeight and that didn't work.

Comment: @Brandon This is different from my comment. [I even have it working on your plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0sBDD0AcVVKoAwk4iGyN?p=preview).

Comment: Oh, sorry. I can't believe you got it to work. I've been trying to get around this issue for over a day. Thank you

Comment: Fresh set of eyes always helps. Make sure to use strings in your `$watch` statements. It's easier to read, and I'm 99% sure it's supposed to be a string anyways.